# The feature of locking method in dbms

Tags: database, timestamp, serializable, strict

I am newer in database design ,i want to know some features of locking protocol in dbms .

My features are:

- Deadlock Free
- View/conflict serializable
- Recoverable
- Cascadeless

And my protocols are :

- 2pl
- Strict 2pl
- Graph based
- Timestamp
- Validation
- Basedmulti granularity

I want to know every protocols features value(that is said before). For example for 2pl :

- Is it deadlock Free?
- Is itVeiw/conflict serializable?
- Is it recoverable?
- Is it cascadeless?

Comment: I searched it ,but every website has different idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want someone to write a book for you. I suggest you break this question down to a number of questions that someone can answer in less than 10 or 15 minutes. Also, I suggest you ask them in the Stack Exchange site devoted to Computer Science since these seem theoretical rather than linked to any implementation.

Cheers -